# How did Serpent the animal know the wrong before Adam?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, evil-inclination

*This question deals exclusively with the literal interpretation of the Serpent as a biological species, not as metaphorical evil* (see my previous question ["Stripping-satan-of-his-legs"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126303/meaning-of-stripping-satan-of-his-legs-and-walking-on-his-belly)).

In plain understanding, the Serpent's intention was evil, it clearly intended to fail Adam and Eve.

Only after eating the forbidden fruit, God announced that Adam is now "like them" knowing good and evil, even though he was created in God's image.

The Torah says that the Serpent was [created] most ערום of all animals, but as an animal, where did it get the understanding of evil from, before Adam?

Comment: (1) The fact that serpent's intention _was_ evil, doesn't mean it _knew_ what evil was. (2) You may be conflating 'right vs. wrong' with 'good vs. evil'.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/does-satan-know-our-thoughts

Comment: Not sure where you get the idea that the serpents intention was evil.